# Angular Breakpoint service fails in print

Tags: angular

I am creating a project using Angular. In my projects, I am using breakpoint service to handle some condition on mobile devices, but when I use print feature, this breakpoint service calls in print mode.

```js
this.breakpointObserver
  .observe([Breakpoints.Handset])
  .subscribe((result) => {
    if (result.matches) {
      // update Layout
      this.acctTileView = true; // only tile view is available on mobile device
     
    }
    else {
      // update Layout
      //this.acctTileView = false;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to handle any javascript for the print layout.
You will need to handle the layout changes with css or run the javascript just [before printing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeprint_event).